# Show close button for each item and hide current item with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, events, dom

I have an `<ul>` list with some `<input>` fields and I need show the `<span class="delete-link">` element on mouse over the actual field.

And when the user clicks the `X` close button, hide the current `<li>` element from the list.

I'm trying to do this with **vanilla JavaScript** and I'm stuck at this point. My code shows only the first close button, no matter what field I hover in.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="social-links-list">
  <li class="social-link">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="http://facebook.com/id">
    <span class="delete-link" onclick=''>X</span>
  </li>
    <li class="social-link">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="http://facebook.com/id">
    <span class="delete-link">X</span>
  </li>
    <li class="social-link">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="http://facebook.com/id">
    <span class="delete-link">X</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

input[type='text'] {
  height: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.delete-link {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**JS**

```
var socialField = document.querySelectorAll('.social-link');

socialField.forEach(function(el) {
    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        closeBtn.style.opacity = 1;
    });
      el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
        closeBtn.style.opacity = 0;
    });
    var closeBtn = document.querySelector('.social-link .delete-link');

    for (i = 0; i < closeBtn.length; i++) {
      closeBtn[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
      });
    }
});
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcupn5sr/9/).

Comment: Create function that vill get id of the item. and then on click call that function. So you can delete that item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Quite there.

---

Just store your `.delete-link` element in a variable (`closeBtn`) to be more manageable and add a `click` event listener to it:

```js
var socialField = document.querySelectorAll('.social-link');

socialField.forEach(function(el) {
  var closeBtn = el.querySelector('.delete-link');
  
  el.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {    
    closeBtn.style.opacity = 1;
  });

  el.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    closeBtn.style.opacity = 0;
  });
  
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    closeBtn.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

input[type='text'] {
  height: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.delete-link {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<ul class="social-links-list">
  <li class="social-link">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="http://facebook.com/id-1">
    <span class="delete-link">X</span>
  </li>
  <li class="social-link">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="http://facebook.com/id-2">
    <span class="delete-link">X</span>
  </li>
  <li class="social-link">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="http://facebook.com/id-3">
    <span class="delete-link">X</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I changed the **placeholders** of your input fields in order to be clear, that **the right element was modified**.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with your closeBtn selector. The way you currently have it written, it isn't actually selecting the child element for you el parent. It is actually grabbing the first item that matches your selector, not ALL items which is what you want.

What you want to do is create a variable specifically for span child.

```
var closeBtn = el.querySelectorAll(".delete-link")[0];
```

That will specifically get the .delete-link span for the current element.  After doing this you can drop the for-loop it's entirely unnecessary.

```
var socialField = document.querySelectorAll('.social-link');

socialField.forEach(function(el) {
    var closeBtn = el.querySelectorAll(".delete-link")[0];

    el.addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
        closeBtn.style.opacity = 1;
    });
    el.addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
        closeBtn.style.opacity = 0;
    });

    closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
       this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    })
});
```

Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0u7jxtfk/2/

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify the code significantly by using css to hide/show the delete link. You can also reference the delete link directly from the social link node.

```js
var socialField = document.querySelectorAll('.social-link');

socialField.forEach(function(el) {
  var closeBtn = el.querySelector('.delete-link');
  closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    el.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

input[type='text'] {
  height: 1rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.delete-link {
  color: red;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.social-link .delete-link {
  opacity: 0;
}

.social-link:hover .delete-link {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="social-links-list">
  <li class="social-link">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="http://facebook.com/id">
    <span class="delete-link" onclick=''>X</span>
  </li>
  <li class="social-link">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="http://facebook.com/id">
    <span class="delete-link">X</span>
  </li>
  <li class="social-link">
    <input type="text" name="" id="" placeholder="http://facebook.com/id">
    <span class="delete-link">X</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```